# What is the Postgres MD5() equivalent in SQL Servrer?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, md5, database-migration

I'm migrating data from **SQL Server 2017** to **Postgres 10.5**.

In order to compare data consistency, I want to perform hashing on the rows in a table.

This is my approach for that.

I'll issue a query on SQL server table and Postgres table and get list of hashes for all the rows. I'll be having two hash lists.

1. SQL Server table hash list
2. Postgres table hash list

I can compare them both and check if the data is consistent.

I found a function to perform hashing on rows in a table in **Postgres**.

```
select md5(f::text) from table_name as f
```

It is returning hashes for all the rows in the table like below.

```
hash1_for_row1
hash2_for_row2
hash3_for_row3
hash4_for_row4
....
```

But I couldn't find an equivalent function or something in **SQL Server** to do the same `MD5` hashing.

I've looked at `HASHBYTES()` in **SQL Server 2017** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

But it does the hashing on only one column. That too on a column which is of `varchar()`.

How do I perform the `HASHBYTES()` function on all the rows and all the columns in a table and not just one column that returns hashes as mentioned above?

Comment: It might also be helpful if you can state how in your application process you were making use of the entire table hash in SQL Server.

Comment: Updated the question. BTW I'm looking for `hash` of each row. Not one `hash` for entire table.

Comment: The equivilent for `MD5` in SQL Server would be [`HASHBYTES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), **however**, you should not be using MD5 any more as they aren't true hashes (as they can be reversed). From the linked document: *"The MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA, and SHA1 algorithms are deprecated starting with SQL Server 2016 (13.x). Use SHA2_256 or SHA2_512 instead. Older algorithms will continue working, but they will raise a deprecation event."*

Comment: In `Postgres`, I've tried using `digest()` function mentioned here http://www.postgresql.cn/docs/9.5/pgcrypto.html But I'm getting error though I have `pgcrypto` extension already installed.

Answer (score 3):

HASHBYTES('MD5',x) in MSSQL is the equivalent of MD5(x) in Postgres. Both functions accept only a single value as input.

What you are really asking is how to replicate the behaviour of ::text, which converts an entire table to an array of text values. One problem with this is that the output of casting a row as text in Postgres is very particular to Postgres. The formatting rules could be difficult to reproduce exactly on another platform and any changes in quoting for example would result in a different hash. A better option might be to convert your data to a more standard format like JSON and then hash that result. For example:

MS SQL:

```
WITH p (ky,val) AS
(SELECT 1,'foo' UNION ALL SELECT 2,'bar')
SELECT j, HASHBYTES('MD5',CAST(j AS VARCHAR(MAX))) AS md5
FROM p AS p1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM p WHERE p.ky=p1.ky FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) AS t(j);

{"ky":1,"val":"foo"}    84C700DA7093081E7A800D1790BE09CE
{"ky":2,"val":"bar"}    A364B3F954F1A875540FE361CABFFD2A
```

PostgreSQL:

```
WITH p (ky,val) AS
(SELECT 1,'foo' UNION ALL SELECT 2,'bar'),
p1 AS
(SELECT row_to_json(p) as j
FROM p)
SELECT j,md5(j::text) as md5 from p1;

{"ky":1,"val":"foo"}    84c700da7093081e7a800d1790be09ce
{"ky":2,"val":"bar"}    a364b3f954f1a875540fe361cabffd2a
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not an expert in DB. It's confusing to me as to where do I pass the table name in the above SQL queries to get the hash values.

Comment: @Sukumar Replace the first two lines of the query with this: "WITH p AS (SELECT * FROM your_table)". For the SQL Server version you also need to replace "ky" in the WHERE clause with the name of key column(s) in your table.